# QEMU virtual machine taking more memory than allocated?

Tags: qemu, virt-manager

I checked with `htop` why the PC stopped responding and why the OOM killer had to kick in, and I see my virtual machine that was allocated 2046 MB of RAM taking up 6627 MB of RAM. What is this and how can I prevent this?
Shutting down the VM and rebooting brings the memory usage down.
Host OS: Debian Bullseye
Guest OS: Fedora 36

[image]

Comment: What does that [picture of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397) show?

Comment: @roaima it's fairly obvious what it is, isn't it? I mention `htop` in the post, and the top row of the image has table headers that one would see in an `htop` output, so it's a screenshot of a row (plus the headers) of `htop` output.

Comment: No it's not. I can't read it. Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: @gapsf I don't understand what that means. I already have specified the maximum amount of RAM to be 2048 MB, as I mentioned in the post. Is that not that link is referring to? Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @gapsf The problem is not that I don't know how to limit RAM usage of a process, I'm sure I can find plenty of articles/posts on that topic if I searched for it, but the problem is that the VM that is allocated 2048 MB of RAM is taking almost three times the allocated amount of RAM.

Comment: @roaima If you physically can not read the text in the image then I apologize, the image is mostly just information that I've already mentioned in the text of the post; so it's not all that important. As I said previously, the image is a screenshot of the row of `htop` output that includes process information for the running QEMU VM.

Comment: Check cat /proc/meminfo | grep Committed_AS on guest. # The amount of memory presently allocated on the system. So you may wrong guest allocate just 2gb

Comment: Qemu may overcommit host memory. Guest too. Locking qemu and guest memory can be enabled via mem-lock=on (disabled by default).  https://www.mankier.com/1/qemu#-overcommit

Comment: @gapsf Unfortunately, I did not get a chance to check that as by the time I realized what was happening the process was already killed. I will make sure to try to check it the next time that happens.

Comment: @gapsf I'll have to look into what "overcomitting" is. Though, it does seem to be what's causing the problem, thank you.

Comment: Does guest have swap?

Comment: @gapsf The guest has swap, yes, about the same amount as the amount of allocated RAM.